# Where should the most frequenctly executed C-code be placed in if-else statement.(Under if or else) And Why?

Tags: c

I need answer for one of the most debated C-question.

1. Where should the most frequenctly executed C-code be placed in if-else statement.(Under if or else) ?
2. Why?

Comment: 1. It doesn't matter. 2. Why do you care ?

Comment: If you have only one `if` it does not matter because it's always checked.

Comment: Because it has effect on execution time.

Comment: It has an effect on execution time when you have lots of `else if` under your `if`. Then you should think of ordering your cases from most frequent to less to avoid some computations.

Comment: "Because it has effect on execution time." -- this is a false premise in the vast majority of cases. Branch prediction on modern CPUs makes it irrelevant how you code your if/else branches.

Answer (score 3):

I would 100% go for clarity of the code here. For example by avoiding double negatives (which you could get by swapping the conditions for the two branches).

Any performance difference will be totally negligable.

Answer (score 1):

**1** If you have only an `if else` structure it does not matter because the condition is checked anyway.

**2** if you have `if` followed by some `else if`s and the conditions inside them require function calls and/or many computations you should think of ordering your cases from most frequent to least to avoid some of the computations. 
**Unless the priority of the checks matters!**